# adding team as collaborator to repo from different org gh api

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to add a team as a collaborator to my repo via gh api. Team is from different organisation than my repository.

```
gh api --method PUT -H "Accept: ${MEDIA_TYPE}" --raw-field permission="admin" /teams/${TEAM_ID}/repos/${GH_ORG}/${REPO}
```

My data is correct, I am owner of both the repository and organisation and still getting  HTTP 422

```
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise-server@3.7/rest/reference/teams#add-or-update-team-repository-permissions"
}
```

Is there anything else, that needs to be done in order to achieve this?